# Search multidimensional array and returning specific value from that array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to search through a multidimensional array for a key => value pair, and then either A) Return the array it belongs to or a different specific key => value pair that exists in the same array.

My array is:

```
$pages = array(
    array(
        'pageId' => 10,
        'title' => 'Welcome',
        'theme' => 'basic'
    ),
    array(
        'pageId' => 11,
        'title' => 'Home',
        'theme' => 'basic'
    ),
    array(
        'pageId' => 12,
        'title' => 'Login',
        'theme' => 'basic'
    )
);
```

I've tried

```
$theme = array_search(10, array_column($search, 'pageId'));
```

but it keeps returning an int and not the value `basic` as I am wanting.

I would like either just the value or an array with the key => value pair or the whole array it belongs to.

Comment: are you talking about this `'theme' => 'basic'`? Do you want `basic` which is the value of theme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this simplest one, hope this will be helpful. Here we are using [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/821174)

```
$result=array_column($pages,"theme" ,'pageId');
if(isset($result[$toSearch]))
{
    echo $result[$toSearch];
}
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_filter, **[live demo](https://eval.in/821186)**.

```
array_filter($array, function($v) use($searchKey, $searchValue) {
  return $v[$searchKey]  == $searchValue;
});
```